# ControlBrushKey throws exception in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

The Unhandled exception is thrown only when I have that ControlBrushKey line, and it does not break pointing to that location.

```
var x2 = new Style();
x2.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, Colors.Red);
myListbox.ItemContainerStyle = x2
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.

Is this PresentationFramework.dll bug or am I missing something? I use .NET4

(PS: I have to do it on code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Colors.Red` returns a `System.Windows.Media.Color` type. Wherever you're using that requires a `System.Windows.Media.Brush` type which is why you're getting the error (there's no implicit conversion from `Media.Color` to `Media.Brush`). You need to convert the color to a brush either using a [BrushConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter.aspx) or just creating a new brush. For example

```
myObject.Background = new SolidColorBrush(x2[SystemColors.ControlBrushKey]);
```

Alternatively, you could add the `SolidColorBrush` object as the Dictionary value instead of `Colors.Red` as `Style.Resources.Add` takes an `object` type for the value.

```
x2.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
```

Which method you choose likely depends on whether you'll be using the `Color` type more often or the `Brush` type. In the case of `ItemContainerStyle` I think the second approach would be easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Second approach seems easier.

Comment: You're welcome :) I think in this case the second approach would be easier as it seems that `ItemContainerStyle` interally requires a Brush type.